# Can Spaces be used on only one monitor (with another displaying just one desktop)?

Tags: display, spaces

I like Spaces, and I like my two-monitor setup. However, I'd like to just use spaces on one monitor, while keeping the other one always showing the same desktop. For example,

- Monitor 1 shows Desktops 1-4, changed with Spaces
- Monitor 2 always shows Desktop 5

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I remember stumbling by a util that did this in Snow Leopard, but that the author said this was very complicated in lion due to drastic changes in the Spaces and Fullscreen APIs. This may be not much help but I'll see if I can find the original site.

Comment: @adamrmcd that would be very helpful indeed. I'm using Snow Leopard myself.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I couldn't find the original utility I was thinking of. The best advice I could find repeats what TheWillington suggested below: fake it out with one app running on all desktops.. http://macbitz.wordpress.com/2008/09/18/making-sense-of-spaces-with-dual-monitors/ .. <rant>Maybe Apple assumes users could get confused splitting multiple desktops on multiple monitors, and cripples Spaces more and more with each major release.</rant> ANyway, if I happen to stumble by the util I will let you know ;)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it can be done...  However, you can assign applications to be present in every space.  So, if you end goal is to be able to have your e-mail always showing, yet use spaces to manage other applications, you could do the following.

1. Set mail.app (or whatever mail program you are using) to be present in every space.  Then drag the windows to your second monitor.
2. Launch several other applications, each in their own space.

Now you can switch from space to space and have Mail available in all of them.

Not exactly what you asked for, but I suspect that it will serve your purposes.

Comment: +1 Might work in some cases. However, this makes it difficult to change the windows shown on monitor 2.